# How to delete preconfigured pages in Community?

Tags: community

1/ I've created few preconfigured pages in my Community by exporting some existing pages created by someone else before.
Some of these preconfigured pages are in fact useless. How to delete them?

For instance, I'd like to remove the last page of this list of preconfigured pages:
[image]

2/ In addition, I'd like to know how to rename a preconfigured page (e.g. replace "Sample" by "Template" in the list above).

Answer (score 0):

1/ To delete a pre-configured page go to Setup > Feature Settings > Digital Experiences > Pages

From the list view, use the `Del` link to delete the appropriate page

2/ To rename a pre-configured page, go to Experience Builder for the community.

Under Pages section, search for the page, click on (...) button to access page settings.
Then rename the page accordingly in properties section.

[image]